# Show loader when nextjs is revalidating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I need a hint how to show a loader when nextjs revalidates specified route. Is there some `isRevalidating` flag in nextjs?

```
const getStaticProps = () => {
   return {
      revalidate: 60,
   }
};
```

If user is browsing my application and there's no need for revalidation (60 seconds havent passed yet), it should work smoothly without loaders. But if the revalidation takes place (every 60 seconds) - a loader should appear.

**Q**: How can I know when the "revalidation" is taking place? Is there some `isRevalidating` flag?

Comment: From my understanding of ISR (and when I've used it) when the site is built, it generates the cache files and uses this until a new request is made. If it's after 60 seconds, Next will update the cache in the background then update the UI with the new data. Then any request made after this within 60 seconds will use that file and so forth. I believe the reason you are experiencing any loading times is due to `next dev`. With dev, it does not cache anything. Try `build` & `start` and try it out. It should load instantly no matter the state of the data.